# Why is my father-in-law's PC flooding our LAN with SSDP / M-SEARCH packets?

Tags: windows-8

After observing several days of really bad WiFi performance (wired connections to the router worked fine), I fired up Wireshark and was surprised to see about 200 packets per second being generated by my father-in-law's Windows laptop.

The Wireshark decoded packets look like this:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
Host: 239.255.255.250:1900
ST: urn:schemas-canon-com:service:ICPO-WFTEOSSystemService:1
Man: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 3
```

I understand that SSDP is part of UPnP, and I'm guessing that his laptop is trying (really hard) to find some service.

But what is it searching for and -- more to the point -- what's the proper way to make it stop (besides my interim solution of powering it down!)?

Comment: canon may suggest its printer or camera related?

Comment: Most likely printer drivers looking for their printer. However, 200 packets per seconds is nothing. It’s too much for this service, but no reason for bad network performance. // edit: It’s the “Canon EOS Wireless File Transfer Utility“.

Comment: FWIW, it appears that 200 SSDP packets per second really did hurt network performance: On our LAN, ping tests to the modem reported a median RTT of 800 ms with some delays over 3s and occasional dropped packets.  Now, with SSDP disabled, I'm seeing RTTs of 2.8 ms.  Much bettah.

Comment: So it’s really “bad modem performance”. :P It’s important to make that distinction. Because your modem does not participate in internal communication (which is what *I* think of when someone mentions “network”) but only Internet access. Your modem (which is actually a router) was probably listening for SSDP requests and choked on this meager amount packets.

Comment: @DanielB: Good point: network != modem.  Updated the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

TaskManager pointed the way: an app called "EOSUPNPSV" was eating up 35% of the CPU.  Laptop's owner confirmed that he's not using a Canon digital camera any longer.  One uninstall later and everything is calm on the network.